# Disable automatic transition of work item in Azure DevOps on commit in Github

Tags: github, azure-devops

I've connected a Github repository with a Azure DevOps project to get the links between work items and commits/pull requests. But if the commit message contains any of the words "Fix/Fixes/Fixed"  it will automatically transition the work item to a Done state which I don't want it to do. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Brgds

Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It`s not possible now. It exists only for Azure Git Repositories: [Enable commit mention work item resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/resolution-mentions?view=azure-devops#enable-commit-mention-work-item-resolution).

There is an official answer: [How to disable closing of work items on commit for GitHub?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/929401/how-to-disable-closing-of-work-items-on-commit-for.html)